# Creating a $provider with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to create a $provider using a fairly simple method ported from my angularjs app.

The original

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.config(function($provide) {

         $provide.provider('foo',function(){
              this.$get = function(){
                  var foo = 'foo';
                  return {
                      foo:foo
                  }
              }
         }
    }  

}());
```

Its pretty straight forward. However when i try implementing this in typescript i get a error on the `this.$get` -> `Property get does not exist`

```
export interface IFooConfig {
    foo:string;
}

export class FooConfig implements IFooConfig {

    static $inject = ["$injector","$provide"];
    constructor(private $provide : angular.auto.IProvideService,
                public foo:string
    ) {   

         $provide.provider('foo',() =>{
             this.$get = () => {  // error here on this.$get
                 this.foo = "foo";

                 return {
                     foo:this.foo
                 }
             }
         })
      }

   }

   angular.module("app").config(FooConfig);
}
```

I feel like this should work otherwise i am doing something very fundamentally incorrect

Comment: In a fat arrow function `() => ...`, the value of `this` is carried over from its containing scope, but the provider function passes a completely different context. First step, change the line back to `.provider('foo', function() {...`, second step - consider what further changes will be needed for the same reason.

Comment: Clearly i did not understand the fat arrow functions correctly. thanks @DCoder.